# Is there a place I can find all the extensions of PHP?

Tags: php, zend-studio

Now I'm seeking of **php_pdo_mysql.dll** version **5.2.5.5**,

only found this:

http://dllcentral.com/php_pdo_mysql.dll/5.2.5.5/

But my **zend studio 5.5** says it's invalid!

Is there any other place I can try my luck?

Answer (score 3):

Brrr, I really wouldn't download binaries (that could do anything they please on the system, and possibly even the web pages that get served) from locations like that.

Isn't PDO included in PHP by default since 5.0?

From the [**PDO installation manual**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php):

> PDO and all the major drivers ship with PHP as shared extensions, and simply need to be activated by editing the php.ini  file:

Comment: Yes,but zend studio has an **internal** one

Answer (score 1):

THe pdo extentions come default with php installation as far as I know.
You should try to uncoment the package in your php.ini file and then reload apache.

Comment: `pdo` and `pdo_mysql`,different

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.requirements.php) I would have thought that you wouldn't need a DLL at all. From [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php):

> PDO ships with PHP 5.1, and is
>   available as a PECL extension for PHP
>   5.0; PDO requires the new OO features in the core of PHP 5, and so will not
>   run with earlier versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Official binaries can be found at:

http://windows.php.net/download/

However, you say you already have a Windows binary. Look at it carefully: you should already have that DLL available. Probably, you need to rerun the installer and select that extension.